# How to use Mysql SELECT CASE WHEN expression

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a select case statement on mysql DB.

```
SELECT 
t.name, t.colour,
CASE WHEN (Amount < 0) AS small,  CASE WHEN (Amount > 0) AS large FROM t
```

Error:
......for the right syntax to use near 'AS small, CASE (Amount > 0)

I want my output like so

```
Name      Colour     Small     Large
item1     red        -35
item2     blue                 48
etc.
```

Been trying with no luck. Help please.

Comment: what does your expected output structure look like? how many columns are there?

Comment: @1000111 just added my expected output to the question

Comment: You're not terminating your `CASE` statements with `END` which makes the syntax invalid. Not only that, `CASE WHEN <some-condition> THEN <some-result> END` is the basic example of using `CASE`. Notice that when `Amount` is less than or greater than 0, you aren't doing anything as a result of that. Recommend reviewing: [Control Flow Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
SELECT 
 t.name, 
 t.colour,
 CASE WHEN (t.Amount < 0) THEN t.Amount END AS small,  
 CASE WHEN (t.Amount > 0) THEN t.Amount END AS large 
FROM t
```

**Understanding `CASE WHEN`:**

**Example #1:**

Suppose,

```
IF n < 0 THEN
    'N is negative'
else if n == 0 THEN 'N is Zero'
else 'N is positive'
```

Let's convert this `if-else if` chain in MySQL using `CASE WHEN` expression:

```
SET @n := -9;
SELECT
CASE WHEN @n <0 THEN 'N is Negative'
     WHEN @n =0 THEN 'N is 0'
     ELSE 'N is positive' END AS output;
```

**Output:**

```
    output
N is Negative
```

**Example #2:**

Now we want to convert the following three if statements in MySQL

```
IF n <0 THEN 'N is Negative'
IF n == 0 THEN 'N is Zero'
IF n > 0 THEN 'N is Positive'

SET @n := 5;
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @n <0 THEN 'N is Negative' END AS negativeOutput,
    CASE WHEN @n =0 THEN 'N is 0' END AS zeroOutput,
    CASE WHEN @n > 0 THEN 'N is positive' END AS positiveOutput;
```

**Output:**

Now the output has three columns:

```
negativeOutput     zeroOutput     positiveOutput
                                   N is positive
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like magic. Thanks for the explanation too, it helps.

Answer (score -3):

You can only alias entire expressions, not individual components of an expression:

```
SELECT ... (CASE WHEN 'foo'='bar' THEN 'baz' ELSE 'qux' ) AS foo
           ^--------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Why aren't you terminating the `CASE` statement with `END`?

Comment: coz it's just a quick/dirty example that obviously won't work in OP's case.

Comment: How then do i separate my Small and Large columns?