# Get number of entries per multiple date intervals using single query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `datetime` > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This will get number of entries during last day. But is it possible to get number of entries for multiple intervals without having to send variation of this query multiple times (`INTERVAL 1 DAY`, `INTERVAL 1 WEEK`, `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`, ...)?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: for example 3 rows with single column, each row having number of entries for day, week and month.

Comment: what if you get 1 row having 3 columns like `last day , last week, last month`?

Comment: yes, sure. sounds even better.

Comment: And what do you mean by last week? is it last 7days? And what do you mean by last month? is it last 30 days?

Comment: by last week I mean what `INTERVAL 1 WEEK` means: last 604800 seconds (equivalent for day and month).

Comment: The accepted answer is not doing that -- it is starting at midnight of 1 week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need <kbd>[`CASE WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)</kbd> expression to accomplish that.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(`datetime`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND DATE(`datetime`) < CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS lastDay,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(`datetime`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE(`datetime`) < CURDATE() THEN 1 END ) AS lastSevenDays,
    COUNT(*) AS lastThirtyDays
FROM `table`
WHERE   
DATE(`datetime`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

[**How to use CASE WHEN expression**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643056/how-to-use-mysql-select-case-as-syntax)

**Note:** If your requirement is to get result of last day, last 7 days and last 30 days then go with this query.

**EDIT:**

If you have an index on `datetime` field then the above query will fail to use that index. Please use the query given below in order to utilize the index on `datetime`.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(`datetime`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND DATE(`datetime`) < CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS lastDay,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(`datetime`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE(`datetime`) < CURDATE() THEN 1 END ) AS lastSevenDays,
    COUNT(*) AS lastThirtyDays
FROM `table`
WHERE   
`datetime` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY - INTERVAL HOUR(NOW()) HOUR - INTERVAL MINUTE(NOW()) MINUTE - INTERVAL SECOND(NOW()) SECOND)
```

Comment: Clever to have 3 together in one SQL

Comment: I am still reading docs (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/case-statement/) but I guess that last `COUNT` can be `COUNT(*)` as we selected last month in `WHERE` already.

Comment: You are right. Since 30 Days covering the full span in where condition you can use `COUNT(*)` in place of that. Corrected it.

Comment: OK, works exactly as needed. I did not know about `CASE WHEN` inside of `COUNT`. Thanks.

Comment: Please go through the example link I've shared. It's quite trivial.

Comment: Btw. is it possible to use `IF ... THEN` instead of `CASE WHEN ... THEN`?

Comment: Yes. it's possible. Do you need this?

Comment: I already have solution, so I am just playing with what is possible inside `COUNT`. Any idea why this does not work? `COUNT(IF datetime > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) THEN 1 END) AS HOUR` I am getting error message... While this works `COUNT(CASE WHEN time_start_nginx > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS DAY,`

Comment: You have use `IF` in wrong manner. `IF` works like this : `IF(condition,result_returned_if_condition_is_true, result_returned_if_condition_is_false)`.  Use this `COUNT(IF(`datetime` > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , 1, NULL))`

Comment: You talk about https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-function/ but there also is https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-statement/, similar to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/case-statement/

Comment: `SUM(boolean)` is the same as `COUNT(CASE WHEN boolean THEN 1 END)`, but a lot shorter.

Comment: There's difference between `IF()` function and `IF statement`. You can only use `IF` statement in stored programs (e.g. stored procedures).

Comment: Alternatively you can use `SUM(boolean)` like `SUM(DATE(`datetime`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND DATE(`datetime`) < CURDATE()) AS lastDay`

Comment: @RickJames `SUM(bool)` is even perfecter! Now I realised that `COUNT(bool)` did not work, because `COUNT` counts only `NOT NULL` values, while `SUM` converts `bool` to `integers` and then counts ones and zeroes...

Comment: Yes. You can have a look at the subtleties of count [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68544/0) @Martin